# Service layer for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture

I am currently in the midst of designing an architecture for an enterprise class system based on Google App Engine. I'm looking to leverage jQuery and/or Google Closure on the FE, App Engine HRD on the back end.

I could use some help in deciding how to structure the service layer feeding the FE and working with App Engine datastore on the back end.

In a nutshell my expectation of the service layer:

- Provide a restful API to provision the JSON representation of models;
- Support authentication with Google account (OAuth2... App Engine supports this beautifully but I'm not particularly sure on the best way to secure my services and RESTful APIs);
- Support a MVP/C-style framework to enable modular development.

I was going to use Spring MVC but I read that Spring MVC with App Engine causes slow warm up times. So I'm not really sure about that. I am familiar with GWT but it does not give me a control of my HTML, CSS and JS to a level I would like, particularly since I need to work with JS quite a bit).

Any suggestions or help in this regard would really appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into GAE endpoints?

Comment: "GWT but it does not give me a control of my HTML, CSS and JS to a level I would like" ?? WTF ?! AFAIK, there is no limit to what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Play framework for a couple of projects:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/home

It's mostly nice, but you're stuck with 1.2 since Play 2 doesn't run on GAE. As far as I know there are no new releases of the 1.2 branch coming out anymore so perhaps not the best option to start a new project with.

The thundr framework seems to be much more aimed at GAE itself and works better for those parts, but it's more basic than Play and the community is much smaller. I've done only one small project with it, but it seems fine:
http://3wks.github.io/thundr/